# Identify customers based on their # of transactions

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS access table which has the following structure

```
Trans ID*|Cust ID|Qty|Value
----------------------------
001|A201|5|100
----------------------------
002|B501|2|20
----------------------------
003|A201|2|30
----------------------------
004|A201|-1|-10
----------------------------
005|A201|5|500
----------------------------
```

I need to find out the list of customers who have got more than 3 transactions (excluding transactions which have negative quantity). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Hint: `GROUP BY`

Comment: also `HAVING`, although your example table won't return any records as A201 has exactly 3 transaction and not more.

Comment: I did try the below query. I am also getting the number of transactions/customer. But cannot exclude the less than 3 transaction customers.
SELECT t.cust_id AS CUSTOMER, (select count(ID) from Transactions s where s.cust_id=t.cust_id ) AS NUMTRANS
FROM Transactions AS t;

Answer (score 0):

Did take some in-house help, and I found the answer. Thanks for the hints every one.

```
select COUNT(CUST) from (select cust_id as CUST, count(ID) 
as NUMTRANS from Transactions where Qty>0 group by cust_id) where NUMTRANS>=3
```